# I am trying to open the Gmail login page using selenium in javascript but it's just opening the google page

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation

let webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'), By = webdriver.By, until = webdriver.until; let driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build(); await driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/');

Comment: try to hit `https://accounts.google.com/` url in incognito mode and check what's the behavior there.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it with the using navigation method.

```
driver.navigate().to('https://www.somesite.com/#');
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/navigation-methods-webdriver-examples#:%7E:text=Navigate.To(URL)&text=Purpose%3A%20This%20methods%20Load%20a,be%20a%20fully%20qualified%20URL.)